# Parallel computation of eigenvectors

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Diven a matrix (n*n), is it possible to parallelize the computation of eigenvectors (using MPI for instance)? Before posting this question, I've been searching about this but I didn't get an answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are some papers, like [this](http://wwwmayr.in.tum.de/konferenzen/Jass09/courses/2/Kleine_Albers_paper.pdf), that describe methods.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look at [slepc](http://slepc.upv.es/)